# Replacing ranges with cell refrences

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have hundreds of formulas that contain cell ranges, for instance `sum(A1:A50)` or `sum(A19:BA19)`.  How can I replace the range with individual cells? For example, `sum(A1:A50)` would become `sum(A1,A2,A3,A4...A49,A50)`.  I've tried writing a macro that descends through the highest referenced row, looking for a colon within a formula, but it's very hard to get the column references correct.

If it matters, all of my formulas are nested. Meanning, I might have the sum() within an ifferror() and a division or Mod operator.

Does anyone have any ideas, I'm looking for a fresh approach.

Thank you.

Comment: please post what you've tried and explain what exactly is your issue. Without that your question is too broad and off-topic here. Hint: you may use `Range.Address` property to get cell's address easily.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I have deleted my code, it didn't' work. I need to modify the formula to reflect only individual cell references. While Range.Address might return $A$1:$a10, I need the formula to change to A1,A2,A3...A10 (with or without the absolute reference).

Comment: I edited the question to reflect nested formulas.

Comment: it sounds like "please do my job for me". Sorry, this isn't a site where those questions are on-topic.

Comment: I'm looking for ideas for a fresh approach, I'm not sure where to begin. That is not off topic.  Looping through the formula looking for colons didn't seem to be a fruitful approach, I'm interested in how the community would approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got bored and was a good puzzle.

```
Sub rangesplit()
Dim fnlStr As String
Dim strstrt As String
Dim rngsplit() As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim str As Variant
'Change Selection to the range you want. If more than one cell you will need a loop
fnlStr = Selection.Formula
'remove the part before and including the "(" and store in a variable.
strstrt = Left(fnlStr, InStr(fnlStr, "("))
fnlStr = Left(fnlStr, Len(fnlStr) - 1)
fnlStr = Replace(fnlStr, strstrt, "")
'Split the rest on "," in case of multiple ranges.
rngsplit = Split(fnlStr, ",")
'clear fnlstr and start peicing back together
fnlStr = strstrt
'Loop through resultant array
For Each str In rngsplit
    'Check if viable Range
    If Not IsError(Range(str)) Then
        'Loop throug range
        For Each rng In Range(str)
            'Append each address to fnlstr
            fnlStr = fnlStr & rng.Address & ","
        Next rng
    End If
Next str
'remove the extra "," and replace it with ")"
fnlStr = Left(fnlStr, Len(fnlStr) - 1) & ")"
Selection.Formula = fnlStr
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a great start, thank you for the approach--I'm glad you thought it was a nice puzzle.